# When removing software "you cannot call a method on a null-valued expressions" error

Tags: powershell, scripting, windows-server-2012-r2

I know there are other threads with this question but they all involve code that I don't understand. I know very little of scripting and I'm looking for someone to help me with an easy to understand answer.

I am trying to remove a program with PowerShell (the program doesn't have an uninstaller file).

I can remove it with *Control Panel → Programs and Features*, but I would like to do this remotely with a PSSession. So after some searching on Google I found the following script.

I first run

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Select-Object -Property Name
```

Which gets me the name of the program I want to delete: "OpenOTP-CP (64 bit)"

I then run the script:

```
$app = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Where-Object { 
    $_.Name -match "OpenOTP-CP (64 bit)" 
}
$app.Uninstall()
```

I then get the following error

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Remote2.ps1:4 char:1
+ $app.Uninstall()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Could someone maybe help me by telling me what is wrong or providing me with the correct code?

- OS: Windows Server 2012 R2
- Source for the script: http://lifeofageekadmin.com/how-to-uninstall-programs-using-powershell/

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like `$app` may be an empty variable. I would add a temporary `write-host "app is: $app"` before you call `$app.uninstall()` to check if that is the case.

Alternatively, you could add some logic like this:

```
If ($app){
    $app.Uninstall()
}else{
    write-host "app was not found"
}
```

The reason $app might be empty is because the `-match` operator uses regular expressions, so it's likely treating the brackets as special characters. Try using `-like` instead of `-match` and surrounding it with asterisks:

```
$app = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Where-Object { 
    $_.Name -like "*OpenOTP-CP (64 bit)*" 
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, with the -like operator it worked!

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way and it would be faster.  I'm assume it's an msi provider.

```
get-package "*OpenOTP-CP (64 bit)*" | uninstall-package
```